# Android - Change Emulator Screen Orientation

Tags: android, orientation

I really don't know how to change my screen orientation of emulator.

It show like this:

[image]

Comment: try `ctrl+f11` and check what happens

Comment: Now looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/h53cwy643/ ... I need the portrait orientation.

Comment: I suggest trying out genymotion or another 3rd party console

Comment: I think it's a completely different question from manually rotating the emulator. Here he asks why the emulator is displaying the incorrect rotation.

Answer (score 0):

While creating Emulator you have given the width more than the height. As per your expectation, create a new emulator with height(e.g.800) more than the width(e.g.480). And use CTRL + F11 to change the orientation.